# Can I pass values to an event handling function?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I would Like to use a function with parameters on the properties box with event list. this even list box on the right int he visual studio only allows some functions with object sender and eventargs e, and doesn't show a custom function with parameters. Is this a general behavior or should I look for an error?

Comment: Does your event work when you bind to it?

Comment: You can set parameters in custom Events(inherited from EventArgs) object as e.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the `CommandArgument` of your button.

`yourButton.Click += new EventHandler(yourButton_Click);
  yourButton.CommandArgument = "your parameters";`

and in the event handler method do the following:

`string yourParameters = (sender as Button).CommandArgument.ToString()`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Write a descendant of EventArgs.

e.g.

```
public class MyEventArgs: EventArgs {
    public MyEventArgs(string arg1, int arg2) {
        this.MyValue = arg1;
        this.MyNumber = arg2;
    }

    public string MyValue;
    public int MyNumber;

}
```

Nows it's an okay parameter for an EventHandler, when you write one e, will have MyValue and MyNumber properties.

Answer (score 0):

`Button.Click` is defined as it is, and there is no way to change it. However,

```
yourButton.Click += delegate { YourButton_click(1); }
```

will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

you can only register handlers on an event which correspond to the event declaration (delegate signature).

If you want to use predefined event and dont create your own you have to follow the event handler signature

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of using events in .Net is the following:

- use a delegate with a name that ends with `EventHandler`
- this delegate with have exactly two parameters, `sender` and `e`. `sender` must be of type `object` and should contain a reference to the instance of the class that raised the event. `e` must be of a type that inherits from `EventArgs` (often `EventArgs` itself). `e` is the instance that contains the event data.

You must not expect to find any other event handler signature, it's always `(object sender, XXXEventArgs e)`.

Note that when you raise events and do not need to pass event data, `EventArgs.Empty` should be used.

```
public delegate void MyEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

public event MyEventHandler MyEvent;

public void OnMyEvent()
{
    if (this.MyEvent != null)
    {
        this.MyEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```